# rails link_to fails inside render layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, render, erb, link-to

i try to render this peace of erb:

```
<%= render(layout: "admin/shared/layouts/page_header", locals: { title: title, subtitle: subtitle }) do %>
  <% link_to(admin_users_path, {:class => 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'}) do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
    <%= t('cancel') %>
  <% end %>
  <% link_to('#', {:class => 'btn btn-sm btn-success'}) do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>    
    <%= t('save') %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But it does not render it correctly. Instead of 2 links i have only 1. Does someone see my mistake????

Here the result:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>
    <span title="translation missing: en.new_user" class="translation_missing">New User</span>
    <small> </small>

    <div class="pull-right">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">    
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i>
        <span title="translation missing: en.save" class="translation_missing">Save</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </h1>
</div>
```

using rails 4.2.1 with ruby 2.2.1

Comment: You are missing an equal sign for your first link_to method on your erb tags

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just forgotten an `=`. Your `link_to`s need to be:

`<%= link_to XXX %>`

The last one is appearing at the moment because your `render layout` block is displaying the last value in the block it contains, which is your last `link_to` call in this case.

Comment: I added an explanation.